# Postgres + Npgql + timeout while getting a connection from pool issue

Tags: c#, postgresql, iis, npgsql

My Web application is using Npgsql 2.2.5 and Postgres 9.4. When multiple users tried to access the application, it was throwing an error

> Timeout While getting a connection from pool

On restarting the Application Server (IIS), it started working for a while. Can anyone please help me  in this .

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: show how you are accessing the database. Is it possible you are not disposing the connections and, as more processes are spawned, you are running up to the limit?

Comment: I'm using "Using" statement so that it will dispose after the use.
Eg: using(conn){
}

Comment: can you show code? are you using long-running queries? can you post the entire exception message, including stacktrace? how many users is "multiple"? 2? 10? 100? What is server performance like when the error occurs? The problem may not actually be with postgre or the application, but the resources on the server.

Comment: You should also look at the PostgreSQL error log for the time in question

Comment: Is it possible for Postgres Server to close any unclosed connections?